# how can i filter listview builder of flutter where in the data is fetched from firebase using getx?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

so I'm using getx to to fetch data from firebase to a listview card where in i have multiple data on it and i want to search by any data that is present on the card to filter out a specific card that is searched by any of its value.

[image]

```
class BookController extends GetxController {
  static BookController instance = Get.find();

  late CollectionReference collectionReference;

  RxList<BookModel> books = RxList<BookModel>([]);
  //search
  RxList<BookModel> foundBooks = RxList<BookModel>([]);

  @override
  void onInit() {
  super.onInit();
  collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("books");
  books.bindStream(getAllBooks());
  //search
  foundBooks.value = books;
 }

  void filterBooks(String bookName) {
  List<BookModel> results = [];
  if (bookName.isEmpty) {
    results = books;
  } else {
    results = books
        .where((element) => element["name"]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(bookName.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
  }
  foundBooks.value=results;
}
  Stream<List<BookModel>> getAllBooks() => collectionReference.snapshots().map(
  (query) => query.docs.map((item) => BookModel.fromMap(item)).toList());

}
```

filterBooks function is used in searchBar widget as:

```
  onChanged: (value) => controller.filterBooks(value),
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `BookModel` looks something like this:

```dart
class BookModel {
  String name;
  String year;
  String callNo;
}
```

```dart
var searchFor = 'SearchForMe';

searchFor = searchFor.toLowerCase();

foundBooks.clear();

foundBooks.addAll(books.where((book) =>   
  book.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchFor) 
  || book.callNo.toLowerCase().contains(searchFor)  
  || book.year.toLowerCase().contains(searchFor)  
  || ( ... )
));
```